# Custom Villager Summon Command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to summon a Villager that buys 64 Planks of any kind and giving you 1 gold nugget I have tried using

```
/summon Villager ~1 ~ ~ {Invulnerable:1,CustomName:Wood_Buyer,Profession:0,Career:1,Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:planks,Count:64},sell:{id:gold_nugget,Count:1}}]}}
```

Which allows the player to swap 64 Oak Planks for 1 Gold Nugget.  How would I add another trade for Birch, Spruce, etc. wood?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Damage:` value. For example, this villager will buy oak, birch, spruce and jungle wood:

```
/summon Villager ~1 ~ ~ {Invulnerable:1,CustomName:Wood_Buyer,Profession:0,Career:1,Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:planks,Count:64},sell:{id:gold_nugget,Count:1}},{buy:{id:planks,Count:64,Damage:1},sell:{id:gold_nugget,Count:1}},{buy:{id:planks,Count:64,Damage:2},sell:{id:gold_nugget,Count:1}},{buy:{id:planks,Count:64,Damage:3},sell:{id:gold_nugget,Count:1}}]}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I have been fiddling with this for the past hour and my head was ready to explode.

Comment: Just as an addendum, I have a feeling this command is too long to work through chat, so it will need to be entered through a command block, but that's simple enough.

Comment: @MBraedley Original command is too long also, so they're probably already doing so.

Comment: It's more for the future peoples.

Comment: @MBraedley yeah colorfusion is right, I am using this in a Command Block. I am trying to make a Skyblock map with Custom Trades.  I'll probably post it to PlanetMinecraft later in the month or next month.